# BVH collision traversal algorithm not looking within each descendant

Tags: collision-detection, bounding-volume

I'm looking at [this code](https://github.com/idmillington/cyclone-physics/blob/master/include/cyclone/collide_coarse.h) from [Game Physics Engine Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012369471X) for a BVH traversal algorithm, specifically `getPotentialContacts` and `getPotentialContactsWith` at the end of the file.

By the looks of this algorithm, it'll compare an initial pair of siblings, but it won't look for collisions within each descendant.

I can't see how this would work on a graph like this one, where dotted lines represent branches, solids are leaf nodes, and the tree depths are represented by spectrum colors (red, orange, yellow, green):

[image: BVH problem]

What is it that I'm not understanding here? Do I need another algorithm to find all the contacts within a tree?

I also tried traversing down each of the leafs, but then I end up detecting the collisions twice in many cases -- so that's not it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the same problem with this function... so I tried a few approaches and I ended up with this:

```
  private  int getPotentialContactsWith(
         BVHNode other,
        Vector<PotentialContact> contacts,boolean descend) {

      int count=0;
      //System.out.println(id+" comparando com "+other.id+" contacts.size:"+contacts.size());
      checks++;
      // Early out if we don't overlap or if we have no room
      // to report contacts

      if ((descend) && (!isLeaf())) {
         count += children[0].getPotentialContactsWith(
               children[1], contacts,descend);
      }

      if ((descend) && (!other.isLeaf())) {
         count += other.children[0].getPotentialContactsWith(
                other.children[1], contacts,descend);
       }


        if(!overlaps(other)) return 0;




      // If we're both at leaf nodes, then we have a potential contact
      if (isLeaf() && other.isLeaf())
      {
          if (!alreadyInside(body,other.body,contacts)){
              PotentialContact contact=new PotentialContact(body,other.body);
              contacts.add(contact);} else {errors++;}
          return 1;
      }


      // Determine which node to descend into. If either is
      // a leaf, then we descend the other. If both are branches,
      // then we use the one with the largest size.
      if (other.isLeaf() ||
          (!isLeaf() && volume.getSize() >= other.volume.getSize()))
      {
          // Recurse into ourself
          count += children[0].getPotentialContactsWith(
              other, contacts,false
              );

          // Check we have enough slots to do the other side too
              count += children[1].getPotentialContactsWith(
                  other, contacts,false );
      }
      else
      {
          // Recurse into the other node
          count += getPotentialContactsWith(
              other.children[0], contacts,false);

          // Check we have enough slots to do the other side too
              count += getPotentialContactsWith(
                  other.children[1], contacts,false
                  );

      }


      return count;
    }
```

////
About the code:
Well, its in java but I guess its easy to translate or understand what it is doing.
I created the function "alreadyInside" to check if I already added the potential contact and I was increasing the variable errors if I did, so far this code is not adding any repeated potential contact (errors=0), so I will problably drop this function to optimize the code.
Also, I added the "descend" parameter, which is a flag which tells when to go further down in the structure.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. I'll let you know when I implement node updating, so I can share that with you.